# Strtotime return a negative number

Tags: php, strtotime

I want to get the difference time between Now and today midnight but I get a negative number. Why?

```
  echo strtotime('today midnight') - strtotime("now");
```

Comment: Today at midnight is farther away than now, for PHP, so it's a negative integer. Maybe you meant **yesterday** at midnight?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier In fairness, NIST says "today midnight" could be either one. PHP apparently settles on "tonight". https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/times-day-faqs

Comment: @ceejayoz good point. Let me edit the snark away

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in ceeyajoz's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827647/strtotime-return-a-negative-number#comment88659789_50827647), midnight is relatively unclear, see [this reference link](https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/times-day-faqs).

As for your question, consider this [eval.in script](https://eval.in/1020200).

Yesterday midnight is not the same as today midnight, which is sooner than now. It seems that `midnight` means the midnight that happened at the beginning of the present day. Considering that, it's understandable that you get a negative integer, since midnight already happened.

As mentioned in yet another useful [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827647/strtotime-return-a-negative-number/50827689?noredirect=1#comment88660043_50827689):

> @user3066977 If you want the time left until midnight, do `strtotime('tomorrow midnight') - time()` or `strtotime('tomorrow 00:00:00') - time()`

Comment: the same problem echo strtotime("yesterday midnight") - strtotime("now");

Comment: i do SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_accomplish_date < strtotime("yesterday midnight")   
and i don't get any  result

Comment: @user3066977 in all honesty, I don't know by heart all the string time possibilities, maybe search for the one you need. The question was "why is it a negative integer", the answer is "because midnight is farther than now".

Comment: so there is no difference between yesterday midnight and today midnight ?

Comment: @user3066977 If you want the time left until midnight, do `strtotime('tomorrow midnight') - time()` or `strtotime('tomorrow 00:00:00') - time()`